# Head.js- when to use for improving performance(reducing load times)?

Tags: javascript, head.js

Head.js seems like a fantastic solution for reducing the load times of both your page and external .js files.
But the performance gains in terms of quicker page loading have a great deal to do with both the size and number of external scripts you are using.

At what point does it make sense to use a utility like Head.js?

When the combined total size of your external files is larger than a certain figure?
Is there a general rule to follow here? Trying to avoid using unnecessary scripts if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The head.js script itself is tiny. For any moderately complex Javascript web application, there are performance gains that can be realized by using head.js, so I wouldn't fret about the additional overhead of including head.js with your web application. The advantage of head.js is that you are able to load your scripts in a non-blocking fashion, so it makes sense even if you are only including one Javascript file. This will prevent the inclusion of this file from blocking the rest of the rendering and loading work that needs to be done.

Comment: If that's the case will definitely look into using it for all my projects.